# Consecutive days visited counter suddenly changed its value

Tags: bug

I'm trying hard to get the ***Fanatic*** badge. Today I've noticed that my *"consecutive days visited"* counter decreased and it's 26 currently, however I'm sure that 7-8 days ago the value was 60 something. Can someone look at the logs? If nothing is wrong why I've been shown a wrong counter for so many days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed [@Philip Kendall's advice](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/821/12991) and contacted the Stack Exchange team through contact form. Here is the response:

> Hello,
>
> It's possible that the day you missed never updated the consecutive
>   count correctly in your profile and that it was recently corrected (it
>   is stored as a simple number in a denormalized field in the database).
>   However, your current status is accurate. There was no activity logged
>   for July 22nd and the day was not counted. It's not possible for
>   activity to be subsequently deleted after it had been recorded.
>
> Regards,
>   Stack Overflow Team

Answer (score 3):

This is something you'll have to [contact the Stack Exchange team about](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/contact); even the moderators quite rightly don't have access to to that level of detail about a user's activities.

Comment: Thanks Philip, but what about let's say [this question](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/437/12991) that was answered by SE Community Manager? I thought the [tag:bug] tag will attract their attention.

Comment: The Stack Exchange world was a lot smaller in 2013 :-) If the community managers and/or developers do see this question then great, but if not then the contact form is the next place to take it if you're still concerned about the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot then, I'll contact them through contact form.

Comment: @gdrt We do come by and look at things, I promise! But I _can't_ promise that we'll see every post _immediately_. (Also, you're more likely to attract devs than CMs with the [bug] tag. And then, if it's not an actual code-related bug, probably get no response from them.) Looks like this specific case got answered via e-mail, at any rate.

Comment: Thanks @Pops, they have already answered my question and I posted it [here](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/825/12991).